# How to configure maximum concurrency of Node.js HTTP server?

Tags: node.js

I want to restrict HTTP server to processing at most 1 request at a time. The use case is to enable linear-inspection of the logs when troubleshooting.

In principle, I could implement the queueing logic in the [`requestListener`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener). This would simply require to know when the last request has been handled.

However, I wonder if there is a lower-level approach, e.g. delaying the connection response.

Comment: An Idea would be to rewrite `libuv` to handle just a single callback at a time, and then recompile node with the new `libuv` implementation.

Comment: I have ended up putting an [tag:HAProxy] in front of the [tag:node.js] service.